# Данные высот в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Каким образом и в каком типе БД лучше (по производительности и памяти) хранить данные высот ландшафта?

Есть исходные данные в виде сетки(массива), они охватывают ландшафты и океаны с точностью 15 градусных секунд(500м) на ячейку. То есть это лишь упорядоченный набор точек, характеризующих высоту в по определенной строке(широте) и столбцу(долготе). Данные весят около 13 ГБ. На их основе в режиме реального времени нужно генерировать куски ландшафта в любой позиции и с любой детализацией.

Если на этом остановится, то сразу можно решить: а почему бы их в таком виде и не хранить в БД, а значения получать по целочисленному индексу?! Таким образом для всей поверхности будут данные с одной точностью, хоть то для океана, где они не существенны, хоть то для горной местности, где важна точность даже более, чем 100м.

К этому всему, данные должны редактироваться и по возможности добавляться новые точки для улучшения точности для конкретной местности. По этому ничего в голову не приходит, как хранить это в таблице реляционной БД в виде значение/долгота/широта, где последние 2 колонки индексированные, но в таком случае понадобится в 3 раза больше памяти(если не больше).

Стоит ли делать по последнему способу, даже не смотря на то, что потребуется в 3 раза больше памяти? Или есть способы совместить эти задачи, где в первой таблице будут вершины со статическими индексами, а во второй - данные с большей точностью для отредактированных участков?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не хранил подобные данные в базе. Так как данные хорошо уже проиндексированы, то их можно хранить в обычном файле/файлах. Зная координаты, очень легко (одно умножение и одно сложение) рассчитать положение в файле. На хранение одной высоты вполне можно отвести два байта. Так как самая высокая гора не превышает 9км, а сама глубокая часть океана - около 12 км, то 32км - хороший запас по разбросу. Два байта - это 65к, то есть - пол метра на единицу.

Теперь о размере файла. 15 градусных секунд - 4*60 = 240 значений на градус. Вся Земля - это 360*180 градусов (да, на полюсах будет бешанная точность, но пока на это не обращаем внимания).  Получается 7 с копейками гигабайт  - это очень хорошо согласуется с Вашей цифрой в 13 гигабайт (видимо по 4 байта отводиться на указание высоты).

Но и 7 гигов в памяти держать сложно. Да оно и не нужно. Как я уже писал выше, на полюсах такая точность точно не нужна (там "градусы" паралелей сильно меньше, чем на экваторе). Также, как Вы сказали, в океане такое также не нужно.

Поэтому, упростим формат. Поделим Землю на "квадратные градусы" (да, они квадратными будут только на экваторе, поэтому в кавычках). всего будет 360*240 (= 86400) таких квадратов. Номер квадрата рассчитывается по такой формуле (долгота + 180) * 360 + широта + 90 (я специально приплюсовал 180 и 90,что бы номер был целым числом).
Для каждого такого квадрата рассчитываем усредненную высоту и записываем в файл. размер такого файла будет 168килобайт, что легко загрузить и держать в памяти постоянно. А вот остальные данные раскладывам по мелким файлам. По одному квадрату на файл. Размер такого файла будет 240*240 * 2 = 112 килобайт. Общее кол-во количество таких файлов будет порядка 20000, так как 3/4 поверхности Земли занимает океан.

Итого, подсумируем. Будет один файл, который хранит усредненные данные. Хорошо применять для быстрой отрисовки. Можно держать в памяти. И есть кучка мелких файлов (на самом деле это все может быть один файл, главное правильную структуру сделать), которые хранят детальную информацию о небольшом участке. Если дальше развить идею, то можно сделать отдельно ещё детализированнее файлы для отдельных участков. Возможно, потребуется ещё один файл индекса, который для каждого квадрата будет хранить доступные карты.

Если Вы знакомы с графами и деревьями, то можете заметить, что это обычная реализаци дерева.

Подобным образом работают карты Google и Яндекса (там, насколько я знаю от 7 уровней вложенности).

Подсумируем. Плюсы этого способа:

- легкое  редактирование
- быстрый доступ к данным
- сильно меньше объем данных (по моим подсчетам - около 2.5 гигабайт), но можно и упаковать.
- можно сделать какую угодно детализацию одного конкретного места и это не будет существенно влиять на общий размер и скорость доступа.

Минусы:

- нужно ковертировать данные в данный формат
- нужно проработать детали формата.

Comment: предполагается, что данные в float, так как цифровой единицы на пол метра не хватит

Comment: если хранить данные так как они изначально представлены - по значению на квадрат. Как тогда внедрять новые вершины, которые должны повышать точность для конкретной местности(может иметь любой периметр)

Comment: для мелких квадратов можно хранить данных хоть double по 8 байт на точку.  Либо хранить разность - в пределах квадрата высота сильно не меняется.

Если нужно хранить данные ещё точнее (допустим квадратами по сантиметру), то можно сделать третий, четвертый уровень вложенности. А можно проще. Если подобных вершин будет немного, то просто в текстовом формате рядом хранить "особые" вершины. То есть, для некоторых квадратов будет два файла - один с разбивкой по четверть градуса, а другой - с особыми точками.

Но мне нравиться идея с вложенностями.

Comment: действительно, хранить в БД не вариант, как оказалось)) По моим подсчетам, чтобы хранить все как индексированные вершины по долготе/широте, нужно почти 40 ГБ, с учетом, что количество вершин по долготе будет снижаться ближе к полюсам, чтобы сохранить примерно одинаковой детализацию на реальный метр))

Comment: допустим, буду хранить 1 уровень - единый файл для всей поверхности с ячейками по 15 секунд. 2 уровень - файлы суши на каждый градус широты+долготы с ячейками по 1 секунде, 3 уровень - файлы с данными от пользователей, допустим с ячейками по 0.1 секунды. И определять значение для вершины следующим образом: если существует файл 3 уровня, брать из него, иначе брать из 2 уровня, если это суша, или 1 уровня в местах, где нет данных 2 уровня. Но вот вопрос, что делать с излишней детализацией ближе к полюсам?

Comment: первый уровень лучше хранить ячейками по 1 градусу. Тогда проблем с переибытком на полюсах не будет. Второй - ячейками по 1-5 минут. и так далее. В самом первом уровне хранить данные по ячейкам не в двух байтах, а в 4. первые два хранят высоту (в метрах), а два вторых указывают доступный уровень детализации на этом уровне. Можно даже по битам (нулевой бит - доступен ли первый уровень - оно будет всегда выставлено, первый бит - доступен ли второй уровень детализации).

Comment: почему 1 уровень по 1 градусу? это же на экваторе тогда на 1 вершину придется 111 км, если конечно вы подразумеваете под вершиной то же, что и я.

Comment: тут нужно найти баланс между детализацией и размером файла. Как я выше писал, на Земле 3/4 - океаны и их покрывать одноградусной сеткой самое оно. А там где уже континент, там будет в силу вступать следующий уровень детализации. Вроде как накладные расходы в сотню килобайт,  но так удобнее.

С другой стороны, можно поделить Землю на большие квадраты (на полюсах это будут треугольники) по 10 градусов. И каждый такой квадрат - это отдельный файл. Но там где океан, можно сделать пустой файл - это просто нулевой уровень.

Тут нужно экспериментировать много.

Comment: В общем, попробую. Сами 3D тайлы модели Земли на QuadTree. Сначала вершины для кусков ландшафта генерировал по градусам+детализация, то есть ближе к полюсам была излишняя детализация, поэтому сделал кол-во вершин зависимо от косинуса широты. Таким образом расстояние от вершин было примерно одинаковым на всех параллелях. Есть идея хранить вершины в виде строк в файлах для каждой детализации и в БД индексы на них, но тогда будет проблема с добавлением этих вершин, просто придется переписывать файл при добавлению в середину даже пары байт